# DataTables jquery plugin not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have used the Datatables plugin successfully before, now I want to use it on another site and not having any success getting it to function.

The css and js are being loaded into the page ok, and the id of my table looks good to me, but I must be missing something...

Here is the link to my page http://pgh3.org/modx/top-runners.html

Please refer to the page source, it can be seen that I have commented out a lot of other javascript references as I thought these might be interfering somehow, but it appears not to be the case

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined jquery.dataTables.min.js:126
(anonymous function) jquery.dataTables.min.js:126
st.extend.each jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
st.fn.st.each jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
j jquery.dataTables.min.js:116
(anonymous function) top-runners.html:53
f jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
p.fireWith jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
st.extend.ready jquery-1.9.0.min.js:1
xt

This error is throwing

Comment: Please provide code snippets directly on your post , rather than having users go off click off site to see the errors. Also you might enable other users to better help you if you are able to narrow down the problem somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console pop up this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'asSorting' of undefined
```

Try to add `THEAD` section and a `TBODY` section in your table.

```
<table id="runTable" border="0" align="center">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>#</th>
           <th>&nbsp;</th>
           <th align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;Name</th>
           <th align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;Hash Name</th>
           <th align="center">Runs</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <!-- Your table body here -->
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Felix, I figured it had to be something simple but I was getting square eyes staring at the screen trying to spot the problem.